# AngularJS - Nested views not showing using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on upgrading a project I found to the latest version of Angular and preparing it for Angular 2 conversion etc. So, I'm using some nested views in Angular using `ui-router`, and I can only get the nested views to display if they are explicitly included in the `index` page as `ng-template` files.

`index.jade`

```
script(type="text/ng-template", id="404")
    include partials/404
script(type="text/ng-template", id="home")
    include partials/home
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/layout")
    include partials/private/layout
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/home")
    include partials/private/home
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/nested")
    include partials/private/nested
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/nestedAdmin")
    include partials/private/nestedAdmin
```

`app.routes.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.routes', [
      'ui.router'
    ])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    var access = routingConfig.accessLevels;

    // Public routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('public', {
            abstract: true,
            template: "<ui-view/>",
            data: {
                access: access.public
            }
        })
            .state('public.home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home'
            })
            .state('public.404', {
                url: '/404',
                templateUrl: '404'
            });

    // Regular user routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('user', {
            abstract: true,
            template: "<ui-view/>",
            data: {
                access: access.user
            }
        })
            .state('user.profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                templateUrl: 'profile',
                controller: 'profileController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .state('user.private', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/private',
                templateUrl: 'private/layout'
            })
                .state('user.private.home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'private/home'
                })
                .state('user.private.nested', {
                    url: '/nested',
                    templateUrl: 'private/nested'
                })

                .state('user.private.admin', {
                    url: '/admin',
                    templateUrl: 'private/nestedAdmin',
                    data: {
                        access: access.admin
                    }
                });

  });

})();
```

I wanted to remove the whole `ng-template` part as I felt this would not be efficient when scaling the app up, so I removed the `ng-template` scripts from the `index` page. When I do this, the first layer of nested routes work, so routes such as `public.home` work okay. The problem comes with the second layer of nested views, so now routes such as `user.private.home` and `user.private.nested` do not work and aren't displayed.

Here is the generated HTML with and without the `ng-templates` scripts:

`WITH ng-templates scripts`

```
<div data-ui-view="" class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 ng-scope">
  <p class="ng-scope">Only visible to users</p>
</div>
```

`WITHOUT ng-templates`

```
<div data-ui-view="data-ui-view" class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 ng-scope"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/247

Turns out it's an issue with Jade/ui-router, I'm not sure which. The solution is to either include `ui-view` using pure HTML `<div ui-view></div>` or by placing `doctype html` at the top of your partial file.

It was a confusing issue because the nested templates worked fine when injected into `$templateCache` using `ng-template` as shown in my post.